# Canvas bug. Javascript distorting array values to be drawn to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgIKD.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbnV4.jpg)I am tinkering with some javascript animations of random sized dots floating on canvas and connecting whenever distance between dots is lower than 150px. Code works just fine except for one part. Whenever i try to draw the lines between dots it changes radius  of every dot in array (except one) to 0px  and applies one velocity to floating dots. I have no idea how that part of code changes everything because it has no affect on array itself and values of array (i have tried console.log(stars) in every part of code where array is visible) . Commenting out code results in array of floating dots of different sizes but with no lines. Any ideas?  (sorry for my broken english)

```
import React ,{useRef,useEffect} from "react";


function App() {

const stars=[];
const star_arr_size=window.innerWidth/10;
var canvasRef=React.useRef(null);

function distance( point1, point2 ){
  var xs = 0;
  var ys = 0;
 
  xs = point2.x - point1.x;
  xs = xs * xs;
 
  ys = point2.y - point1.y;
  ys = ys * ys;
 
  return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}

function define_star(stars){

  for(var i = 0; i<star_arr_size;++i)
  {
    stars.push({
      x:Math.random()*window.innerWidth,
      y:Math.random()*window.innerHeight,
      rad:Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1),
      vx:Math.random()*50-25,
      vy:Math.random()*50-25
    }
    )
  }
  return stars;
}
function draw(stars,ctx){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)
  for(var i = 0; i< stars.length;++i){
  ctx.fillStyle="#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(stars[i].x,stars[i].y,stars[i].rad,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle="black";
  ctx.stroke();

  //FROM THIS
  ctx.beginPath()
  for(var i = 0 ; i < stars.length;++i) {
    ctx.moveTo(stars[i].x,stars[i].y);
    for(var j = 0 ; j<stars.length;++j){
       if(distance (stars[i],stars[j])<150)
       ctx.lineTo(stars[j].x,stars[j].y);
    }
  }//TO THIS
 
}};
 

function update(canvas) {
  for (var i = 0, x = stars.length; i < x; i++) {
    var s = stars[i];
  
    s.x += s.vx / 60;
    s.y += s.vy /60;
    
    if (s.x < 0 || s.x > window.innerWidth) s.vx = -s.vx;
    if (s.y < 0 || s.y > window.innerHeight) s.vy = -s.vy;
  }
}


  
useEffect(()=>
{
  var canvas=canvasRef.current;
  canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
  var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
  define_star(stars)
function tick(){
  
  draw(stars,ctx)
  update()
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);

}
  tick()
})
  



  return (
    <div>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using `var` instead of `let`

Should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; ++i) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(stars[i].x, stars[i].y, stars[i].rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; ++i) {
    ctx.moveTo(stars[i].x, stars[i].y);
    for (let j = 0; j < stars.length; ++j) {
      if (distance(stars[i], stars[j]) < 150) {
        ctx.lineTo(stars[j].x, stars[j].y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You've basically redeclared the same `i` variable

**Remember, never use var**

[image: Edit reverent-shape-b9zpxx]